# package to do SMOTE in R

Tags: r, imbalanced-data, smote

I am trying to do SMOTE in R for imbalanced datasets. I tried installing "DMwR" package for this, but it seems this package has been removed from the cran repository.
I am getting the error:" package ‘DMwR’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2) "

Can anyone please help me with this? Or suggest any other package to use SMOTE in R?

TIA!

Answer (score 5):

You are right. The Error message means that the package is not supported by the newest version of R (4.x.x).

As far as I know the package you are looking for is called "smotefamily" now.

```
install.packages("smotefamily")
```

should give you what you need

Answer (score 5):

`smotefamily` is an option but the syntax is a bit different than the older syntax used in `DMwR`. In fact it does not support the classic formula that is used in `caret`, e.g. `target ~ .` (see documentation `SMOTE(X, target, K = 5, dup_size = 0)` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smotefamily/smotefamily.pdf).

Instead the `performanceEstimation` package has exactly the same formulation of the SMOTE implemented in `DMwR`:

```
smote(form, data, perc.over = 2, k = 5, perc.under = 2)
```

see documentation https://rdrr.io/cran/performanceEstimation/man/smote.html

Answer (score 1):

Big loss with `caret` for subsambling techniques.

You can find available versions from the [archives](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DMwR/), download the desired archive and install it as follows:

```
install.packages("/path/to/archive/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Personally I can't find an available version for R 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)...
I will have to install an older version of R.